# How to access and modify arrays of strings in functions?

Tags: c

I am fairly new to C and I just fell on pointers, I have been doing exercises on it and I looked all over this site and google but I just can't find what I'm looking for. (maybe from inexperience with terminology)

Context I have to use a specific prototype (that the grading program uses) to pass me an array of strings however since I'm limited to 25 lines per function I have tried to pass that same array of strings to another function to no avail, so this was my workaround:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int ft_ultimate_range(int **range, int min, int max)
{
    int *arr;
    int i;
    int j;

    j = 0;
    i = min;
    if (min >= max)
    {
        *range = NULL;
        return (0);
    }
    arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * ((long long int)max - (long long int)min));
    *range = arr;
    if(arr == NULL)
        return (-1);
    while (i < max)
    {
        *range[j] = i;
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    return (j);
}
```

However I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) on vs code at `*range[j] = i;`/ seg. fault when execute on the terminal.

I don't understand why this is as I'm trying to assign values to the passed array if I take the star out I get (incompatible int to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int').

What is going on?

Also can you also please point me to a thread explaining how to pass arrays of strings (or int's between functions)?

Edit: The question if it helps. (I just want to understand what's wrong)

- Create a function ft_ultimate_range which allocates and assigns an array of ints.
- This int array should contain all values between min and max. Min included - max excluded.
- Here’s how it should be prototyped :

  `int ft_ultimate_range(int **range, int min, int max);`
- The size of range should be returned (or -1 on error).
  *If the value of min is greater or equal to max’s value, range will point on NULL and it should return 0

Comment: `*range[j]` is the same as `*(range[j])`, which is very different from the `(*range)[j]` you really want. Or just plain `arr[j]`.

Comment: By the way, there's no array of strings anywhere in the code. 

Comment: I suggest forgetting about "grading programs" for now. Instead, learn C by reading a good structured book, and doing exercises in the order they appear in the book. After you have done that, you can try online grading if you feel like it (although I always considered it a waste of time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `*range[i]` can be read as `*(range[i])`, following the rules of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). This means you are attempting to step into memory adjacent to the address provided by the caller.

Using `(*range)[i]`, or simply using the `arr` variable you created earlier, will solve this.

```
while (i < max) {
    arr[j] = i;
    i++;
    j++;
}
```

With that said, your code is slightly convoluted. While I don't fully agree with the idea of line limits for functions, if those are the constraints you are going to learn under you'll want to try and break problems down into their simplest components & steps needed.

The only additional variables we need are the computed `length` of the range, and the `i`ndex we are inserting values into. There's no need to cast our computed `length` due to [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion). `min` already provides our starting value.

```
size_t range(int **dest, int min, int max) {
    if (min >= max)
        return *dest = NULL, 0;

    size_t length = max - min;

    if (!(*dest = malloc(sizeof **dest * length)))
        return -1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        (*dest)[i] = min++;

    return length;
}
```

Note in this example I've used [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) as it

> [...] can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array).

and is the most appropriate type for indexing said array. You'll want to change every instance of `size_t` to an `int` to match your spec, however.

---

In C, a [*string*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) refers to a sequence of nonzero bytes, followed by the NUL terminating byte (`'\0'`).

Examples of strings:

```
const char *foo = "hello, world";
char bar[] = "Alice";
char baz[] = { 'B', 'o', 'b', '\0' };
```

There are no strings in your code. An example of passing an array of strings can be found by looking at the [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) function, and its second argument.